# Structured data errors on BreadcrumbList with Open Graph

Tags: html, schema.org, facebook-opengraph, google-rich-snippets, rdfa

I recently added the RDFa breadcrumbs structured data to one of our websites. 
Now it looks looks like it conflicts with the Open Graph data that was already present on the website. How is this possible? The OG data is in the `<head>` tag and not even close to the breadcrumbs.

See test: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=EN#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.badkamerwinkel.nl%2Fwastafels%2Fwastafel

URL of site: https://www.badkamerwinkel.nl/wastafels/wastafel

Open Graph code in `<head>` tag:

```html
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="badkamer://categories/79"/><meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Badkamerwinkel"/><meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="1079403656"/><meta property="og:type" content="product.group" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Wastafel nodig?  | Badkamerwinkel.nl" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.badkamerwinkel.nl/skin/frontend/bombastium/default/logo-200x200.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.badkamerwinkel.nl/wastafels/wastafel" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Het grootste Online Wastafel assortiment vind je op Badkamerwinkel.nl > Ruime keuze uit verschillende soorten wastafels > Voor 20:30 besteld, morgen in huis" />
```

RDFa code in `<body>` tag:

```html
<ol vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="BreadcrumbList" class="breadcrumb">
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem" class="home">
    <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://www.badkamerwinkel.nl/" title="Ga naar Home"><span property="name">Home</span></a>
    <meta property="position" content="1">
  </li>
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem" class="category53">
    <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://www.badkamerwinkel.nl/wastafels" title=""><span property="name">Wastafels</span></a>
    <meta property="position" content="2">
  </li>
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem" class="category79">
    <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://www.badkamerwinkel.nl/wastafels/wastafel" title=""><span property="name">Wastafel</span></a>
    <meta property="position" content="3">
  </li>
</ol>
```

[image: Visible errors]

Comment: Do you still get the error? I tested the markup you included but I get no errors. (I couldn’t test the example URL because it doesn’t load currently.)

Comment: This morning I changed the markup from RDFa to Microdata, more info:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs#use_cases

So the issue is fixed by using another syntax.

Comment: 2019 and still the same problem :-(

Comment: 2020 and this is a problem for me, too.